# Select query from c# datatable

Tags: c#, datatable

I have datatable with following columns.

```
 ID
 Name
 Dept
```

I want to select Name where ID = "XXX" from datatable.

Can any one please suggest how can i do that.

Comment: minor aside, but `DataTable` isn't the ideal way of modelling your data; have you considered a POCO model? i.e. `public class Whatever { public int Id {get;set;} public string Name {get;set;} ... }` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
DataRow[] rows = DataTable.Select("ID = 'XXX'")
```

Answer (score 2):

```
dt.AsEnumerable().FirstOrDefault(row => row.Field<int>("ID") == 123);
```